# Código de bucle for no se ejecuta según la condición

Tags: c

Tengo una duda con el bucle `for`, ¿por qué este código no me entrega resultados? No se ejecuta mi programa, que debe de iniciar un conteo en 10 y acabar en 0.

Éste es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   int i=0;

   for (i=10;i<=0;i--)

    printf(" %d ",i);

}
```

Sin embargo, investigando un poco encontré lo siguiente, que sí funciona a la perfección.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   signed int i=0;

  for (i=10;i>-1;i--)

  printf(" %d ",i);

}
```

Mi duda es: ¿por qué el primer código no funciona y el segundo sí?, ¿por qué C no entiende el parámetro `<=0`?

Comment: la instruccion `for` tiene 3 campos, el primer campo es el que inicializa variables, el segundo es una condicional, y el tercero es un tarea que se realiza al acabar de ejecutar el contenido, en realidad son 4 considerando el codigo entre `{}`, en tu primer caso i=10 establece el valor de i en 10, este valor tiene que verificarse con el segundo campo, es decir, `10 <= 0`, que obviamente es falso, al ser falso no se realiza ninguna accion, por ello no funciona tu primer codigo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvio tu comentario para entenderlo, saludos :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Básicamente son las condiciones que tienes, tendrías que tener mas cuidado al crear tus algoritmos.

**En El Primero:**

```
for(i=10;i<=0;i--)
```

tu condición se ve de esta forma `for(i=10;10<=0;i--)` condición que si notas es **falsa(`false`)** desde el inicio, lo que deberías de hacer es

```
for(i=10;i>=0;i--)
```

que se ve como: `for(i=10;10>=0;i--)` lo cual es **verdadero(true)**

**En El Segundo**

```
for (i=10;i>-1;i--)
```

tu condición llega a ser **verdadera** y eso es todo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón amigo, Muchas Gracias, ya lo entendi, saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Como dice **@eyllanesc**

> el primer campo es el que inicializa variables, el segundo es una condicional, y el tercero es un tarea que se realiza al acabar de ejecutar el contenido

En el primero no te funciona ya que estas diciendo que recorra 10 veces la variable i hasta que i(10) sea menor o = 0 por lógica 10 nunca va a ser menor ni igual cero, y el segundo quizás te funciona ya que por lógica 10 es numero positivo y -1 es negativo, pero no tendría sentido recorrer el `for` de esa manera, posiblemente no te mostrara nada.

Comment: Si jaja No mostraba nada, pero con l que me explican ya entendi mi error, gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

En conclusión tu código debería funcionar de la manera siguiente

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   int i=0;

   for (i=10;i>=0;i--)

    printf(" %d ",i);

}
```

para que sea funcional solo cambia el signo < (menor que) por > (mayor que)

para que for se lea de la siguiente manera "itera la variable i con valor inicial de 10, siempre que sea mayor o igual a 0 y después de cada iteración resta 1 al valor de i"

Comment: En efecto, gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

Tu error está en la condición del for donde dice i <= 0.
Debes tener claro que los bucles finalizan una vez la condición es falsa.
Entonces, como i se inicializa en 10 y no es menor a 0, el bucle termina.

Comment: No entiendo porque mi respuesta no es util

Comment: porque no explicas el motivo por el cual falla el codigo original ni tampoco expones ninguna solución... y eso te lo digo sin poner aun negativos... replantea tu respuesta

Comment: No hay problema.  Pero el chico recién está empezando y no me pareció lo mejor darle un explicación de enciclopedia

Comment: este es un portal de preguntas y respuestas... si no respondes a lo que preguntan recibes negativos porque te desvias del tema... si ademas de solucionar el problema crees conveniente complementar alguna idea o explicar algo adicional tanto mejor... pero solucionar el problema o responder a las preguntas planteadas es el contenido básico de la respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, pero yo replantee la respuesta como me sugeriste y tengo un -2 por algo que está bien. Y posiblemente ahora el chico ni pierda su tiempo en leerla. Muchas gracias igual

Comment: no te agobies por la reputación... es un consejo. La gente no vive pegada a la pantalla... hay gente que vota y se pone a hacer sus cosas y lo mismo no vuelve a pasar hasta mañana o no pasa mas por el hilo... cuando empiezas se nota más pero en serio... que un bache de reputación no te eche para atrás... si tus respuestas son buenas conseguirás reputación sin darte cuenta.

Comment: Antes que nada, gracias por responder, es clara tu respuesta amigo, gracias :) Y si ando por acá, nadamas que de vez en cuando como ahorita jeje Saludos

Answer (score 0):

`for (i=10;i<=0;i--)` esto es un error lógico. Estás diciendo que Para i = 10 hasta 0 aumentado y disminuyendo i en 1. Un momento, no se puede ir de un número mayor a otro menor aumentando, por lo tanto la comparación es inadecuada.
En consecuencia está mal es signo de menor. Como comentaron otros usuarios, lo correcto sería: `for (i=10;i>=0;i--)`